# Importar Base de dados em JSON para Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firestore

Tenho 2 bases de dados em json onde uma é de indicações, e a outra são os comentários dessas indicações. Segue o modelo de cada base (com um só dado):

indicação:

```
{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "txt_email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 }
```

comentários da indicação:

```
{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 },
```

Preciso que assim que a indicação seja importada, o meu script faça uma busca na base de comentário e adicione cada comentário dentro de sua respectiva indicação.

Para fazer isso tentei seguir o modelo do artigo: [https://medium.com/lucas-moyer/how-to-import-json-data-into-firestore-2b370486b622#:~:text=To%20add%20this%20data%20to,Almost%20done](https://medium.com/lucas-moyer/how-to-import-json-data-into-firestore-2b370486b622#:%7E:text=To%20add%20this%20data%20to,Almost%20done)!

Meu script final ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

require('firebase/firebase-firestore');

firebase.initializeApp({MINHAS_CREDENCIAIS});

let indicacoes = [{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "txt_email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 },
 ...
];

let comentarios =[{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 },
 ...
];

 indicacoes.forEach( obj => {
   let valorindicacao = obj.id_indicacao;
   firebase.firestore().collection('teste').add({      
      ativo: obj.boo_ativo,
      categoria: obj.categoria,
      sub_categoria: obj.sub_categoria ? obj.categoria : "outros",
      dt_registro: new Date(obj.dt_registro),
      email: obj.txt_email,
      id_cliente: obj.id_cliente.toString(),
      id_usuario: obj.id_usuario.toString(),
      nome: obj.nome,
      criador_indicacao: obj.criador_indicacao,
      txt_unidade: obj.txt_unidade,
      site: obj.site ? obj.site : "Sem site",
      txt_telefone: obj.txt_telefone ? obj.txt_telefone : "sem telefone", 
   }).then( doc => {
     let indicacao = doc.id;
     console.log('documento inserido: ', doc.id);
     comentario.forEach( async comentario => {
       if (comentario.id_avaliacao == valorindicacao) {
         await firebase.firestore().collection('teste').doc(doc.id).collection('comentarios').add({
          ativo: comentario.boo_ativo,
          avaliacao: comentario.nr_avaliacao,
          comentario: comentario.txt_comentario,
          criador_comentario: comentario.nome_autor,
          dt_registro: new Date(comentario.dt_registro),
          id_cliente: comentario.id_cliente,
          id_usuario: comentario.id_usuario,
         }).then( resultcomentario => {
           console.log('incluido com sucesso')
         }).catch(erro => {
           console.log(erro);
         })
       }
     })
   }).catch( error => {
     console.log('occorreu um erro: ', error);
   })
 });
```

Como podem ver, tentei usar a resposta da Promise no .then() para capturar o id que o firestore gerou(**doc.id**), e logo após fazer a busca na base de comentários procurando por comentários que tenha o mesmo id_indicacao da indicação recentemente inserida; caso encontre ele deverá inserir no caminho do **doc.id**, abrir uma coleção "comentarios" e inserir o comentário lá dentro. Acontece que por algum motivo ele não está respondendo da maneira esperada - acredito que por problemas de assincronia ou pelo tamanho da base de dados.

Como faço para importar todos esses dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "acredito que por problemas de assincronia ou pelo tamanho da base de dados."

Neste trecho aqui está o problema de assincronia :

```
 async comentario => {
   if (comentario.id_avaliacao == valorindicacao) {
     await fi .....
```

Frase do artigo:

> "
> Se você puder tirar apenas uma coisa deste artigo, que seja: async/await não funciona em Array.prototype.forEach. Vamos ver um exemplo para ver o porquê:
> "

[Referência](https://oieduardorabelo.medium.com/javascript-armadilhas-do-asyn-await-em-loops-1cdad44db7f0)

Muda o `forEach` para outra forma de iterar:

```
async function getTodos() {
  for (const [idx, url] of urls.entries()) {
    const todo = await fetch(url);
    console.log(`Received Todo ${idx+1}:`, todo);
  }

  console.log('Finished!');
}
```

Mais uma coisa: `comentario.id_avaliacao == valorindicacao` ?

Não é `id_indicacao`?

Comment: Obrigado pela força, vou testar agora mesmo a sua solução! O "valorIndicacao" é uma variável que eu criei apenas para guardar o doc.id. Eu achei melhor indicar assim do que chegar no segundo forEach e escrever "doc.id"

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar uma solução. Realmente o forEach não estava respeitando a iteração do meu script. então criei duas funções que mantém minha iteração contida, e chamo ela no final do meu script.

Segue o código:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

require('firebase/firebase-firestore');

firebase.initializeApp({MINHAS_CREDENCIAIS});

//Aqui declaro as funções enviar_comentarios e enviar_indicações:

let enviar_comentarios = (comentarios, valorIndicacao, doc) => {
  for(ivalue of comentarios){
    if(ivalue.id_indicacao == valorIndicacao){
      firebase.firestore().collection('database').doc(ivalue.id_cliente.toString()).collection('indicacao').doc(doc.id).collection('comentarios').add({
        ativo: ivalue.boo_ativo,
        avaliacao: ivalue.nr_avaliacao,
        comentario: ivalue.txt_comentario,
        criador_comentario: ivalue.nome_autor,
        dt_registro: new Date(ivalue.dt_registro),
        id_cliente: ivalue.id_cliente,
        id_usuario: ivalue.id_usuario,    
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('coisou')
      })
    }
  }
}

let enviar_indicacoes = (indicacoes) => {
  for(ivalue of indicacoes){
    let valorIndicacao = ivalue.id_indicacao;
      firebase.firestore().collection('database').doc(ivalue.id_cliente.toString()).collection('indicacao').add({
      ativo: ivalue.boo_ativo,
      categoria: ivalue.categoria,
      sub_categoria: ivalue.sub_categoria ? ivalue.categoria : "outros",
      dt_registro: new Date(ivalue.dt_registro),
      email: ivalue.txt_email,
      id_cliente: ivalue.id_cliente.toString(),
      id_usuario: ivalue.id_usuario.toString(),
      nome: ivalue.nome,
      criador_indicacao: ivalue.criador_indicacao,
      txt_unidade: ivalue.txt_unidade,
      site: ivalue.site ? ivalue.site : "Sem site",
      txt_telefone: ivalue.txt_telefone ? ivalue.txt_telefone : "sem telefone",      
    }).then( async doc => {
      console.log('deu bom: ', doc.id);
      await enviar_comentarios(comentario, valorIndicacao, doc);
    }).catch( error =>
      console.log(error)  
    )

  }
}

//aqui declaro os dados em json dos comentarios e das indicações:
let indicacoes = [{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "txt_email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 },
 ...
];

let comentarios =[{
   "id_indicacao": 52,
   "boo_ativo": 1,
   "categoria": "Alimentação",
   "sub_categoria": "Cafés e Comidinhas",
   "dt_registro": "2016-03-07 13:30:34",
   "id_cliente": 45,
   "id_usuario": 2678,
   "nome": "Robataria - Temaki & Robata",
   "criador_indicacao": "FRANCISMAR RANGEL DE SOUZA",
   "txt_unidade": "17 Bloco 1",
   "email": "edu@umemail.com",
   "site": "",
   "telefone": "(11) 99389-1773"
 },
 ...
];

//aqui invoco a função:
enviar_indicacoes(indicacoes);
```

O uso do "for ... of" respeitou a iteração e para mim, a solução apresentada funcionou.